# Deferred Sharing mode?

Tags: sharing-rule

What is deferred sharing mode in salesforce ? will the sharing rules work when the deferred sharing mode is on ? I observe that the sharing rules don't work when the deferred sharing mode is on and also the test classes fail because of it. What can be done to make the test class pass ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_defer_sharing_calculations.htm&type=0):

> Performing a large number of configuration changes can lead to very long sharing rule evaluations or timeouts. To avoid these issues, an administrator can suspend these calculations and resume calculations during an organization's maintenance period.

To resume normal operation , simply resume recalculate sharing. again from the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_rule_recalculation.htm&type=0&language=en_US):

> To suspend, resume, or recalculate sharing rule calculation:
>
> 1. From Setup, enter Defer Sharing Calculations in the Quick Find box, then select Defer Sharing Calculations.
> 2. In the Sharing Rule Calculations related list, click Suspend.
> 3. Make changes to sharing rules, roles, territories, or public groups participating in sharing rules. To enable sharing rule calculation,
>      click Resume.
> 4. To manually recalculate sharing rules, click Recalculate.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric. I have read the docs , but I need general info on how actually the deferred mode works. And wanted to know whether the existing sharing rules work or not when this mode is on ?

Comment: Deferred sharing simply suspends the recalculation of sharing rules. Sharing prior to the suspension is maintained IIRC. Its nothing more than that. Maybe someone else can explain it is more detail